# error: package javafx.collections does not exist import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

So right now I'm working on a java project which uses javafx and the aim is to create executable file (first we need jar file atleast), after multiple issues I moved this project to gradle, but now on build it throws this `error: package javafx.collections does not exist import javafx.collections.FXCollections;`

SDK: corretto 17

I tried from moving plain java project to gradle.

Comment: See https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions when setting up your project? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: The plugin (and documentation) for packaging an installable, non-modular JavaFX project using gradle (if that is what you are trying to do),is the [badass runtime plugin](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/).

Comment: @jewelsea managed to setup codebase, but the distribution is not working, it opens and closes it. How we can manage to see the logs and see the error

Comment: That is not really specific about what you are doing and how it is failing, so there is not much I can say.  It sounds like a different question from the original, so perhaps you can ask a new question with more supporting info.  What logs to look at depends on what is failing.  For application logs, you can use a tool like slf4j/logback and write to disk, or the console.  Also if there are messages printed to system out and err they will show in the console.  If you run by double click you may not see messages in the console, but running from the command line can reveal them.